# Как реализовать метод split() (аналог String.split) для класса Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив Uint8Array с бинарными данными в формате

```
multipart/mixed;boundary=Boundary_23_730424359_1491069552303
```

где `Boundary_23_730424359_1491069552303` приведен для примера.

Внутри массива встречаются строки `Boundary_23_730424359_1491069552303`.

Мне нужно разбить массив на подмассивы, аналогично тому, как это делает метод `String.split("Boundary_23_730424359_1491069552303")`.

Как это сделать простым способом?

Это нужно для браузера, не для ноды.

Comment: Вы можете разбить на обычный массив и из него сделать типизированный.

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz Способы конвертации я нашел. Но что это дает? Метода split нет у массива.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел способ:

```
function Uint8ArraySplit(arr, splitter) {
    return arr.join(",").split(splitter.join(",")).map(function(sub) {
        sub = sub.replace(/^,/, '').replace(/,$/, '');
        return new Uint8Array(sub.split(","));
    });
}
```

Правда не понятно на сколько он оптимальный по занимаемому объему памяти. Ведь бинарные данные могут быть большими. А тут по сути много раз они будут дублироваться. Хотелось бы услышать слово экспертов.